# Maximum possible city block distance

Tags: statistics

Anya participated in a study comparing two blood glucose monitors. A total of 20 persons with diabetes participated. Ten participants used Monitor A for two days and then used Monitor B for two days. The other ten participants (including Anya) used Monitor B for two days and then used Monitor A for two days. On the 5th day, participants rated the two monitors on the basis of four features. The four features were rated on a 5 point scale that ranged from −2 (poorly designed) to 2 (well designed). The distance between Anya’s ratings of the two monitors was 4 city blocks. What is the maximum possible city block distance between the two blood glucose monitors?

Comment: City block distance is just the absolute value of the sum, so max is 4 and Anya got the max. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

A participant’s rating of a monitor is a $4$-tuple $\langle r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4\rangle$, where $r_k$ is the rating on feature $k$ for $k=1,2,3,4$; each $r_k\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$. If $r=\langle r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4\rangle$ and $s=\langle s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4\rangle$ are two ratings, the city block distance between them is

$$d(r,s)=\sum_{k=1}^4|r_k-s_k|\;.$$

For example, if $r=\langle -2,0,2,1\rangle$ and $s=\langle -1,-1,-2,2\rangle$, then

$$\begin{align*}
d(r,s)&=|-2-(-1)|+|0-(-1)|+|2-(-2)|+|1-2|\\
&=|-1|+|1|+|4|+|-1|\\
&=7\;.
\end{align*}$$

The maximum possible value of $|r_k-s_k|$ occurs when one of $r_k$ and $s_k$ is $2$ and the other is $-2$, so the maximum possible value of $d(r,s)$ is ... ?